# EclipseLink exception "Connection is read-only" when connect to multi-hosts

Tags: java, mysql

- In persistence.xm l file:

```html
    <properties>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.13:3306,192.168.0.14:3306/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
          <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
        </properties>
```

- I got an exception when long time running:
  `

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only.
>   Queries leading to data modification are not allowed Error Code: 0
>   Call: INSERT INTO vqmm_test (account, code, description, is_free,
>   lastupdate, program_code, received_at, send_sms, service_id, sms,
>   sms_content, sms_detail, status, created_at, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  bind => [15 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(promote.entity.VqmmLuckyCode[
>   vqmmLuckyCodePK=promote.entity.VqmmLuckyCodePK[ id=0, createdAt=Tue
>   Apr 23 14:30:55 ICT 2019 ] ])     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
>     at promote.session.BaseSession.saveBulk(BaseSession.java:209)   at
>   promote.session.BaseSession.saveBulk3(BaseSession.java:305)   at
>   promote.main.Promote.doSaveLog(Promote.java:287)  at
>   promote.main.PromoteThread.run(PromoteThread.java:67)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries
>   leading to data modification are not allowed Error Code: 0 Call:
>   INSERT INTO vqmm_test (account, code, description, is_free,
>   lastupdate, program_code, received_at, send_sms, service_id, sms,
>   sms_content, sms_detail, status, created_at, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  bind => [15 parameters bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(promote.entity.VqmmLuckyCode[
>   vqmmLuckyCodePK=promote.entity.VqmmLuckyCodePK[ id=0, createdAt=Tue
>   Apr 23 14:30:55 ICT 2019 ] ])     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:277)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1169)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:132)
>     ... 5 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only.
>   Queries leading to data modification are not allowed  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2409)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:890)
>     ... 36 more

`
Anyone can help me solve it?
JPA transction support multi-hosts or mysql cluster connection?

Comment: Can you share method definition from where the query is being executed

Comment: Thank Abhijeet, it happened from tx.commit() below.
Remember that if connect to only one host, it never occured.
My lib is used for long time without problem when connect to only one host.
...
tx = emBulk.getTransaction();
if(!tx.isActive()){
 tx.begin();
}            
emBulk.persist(obj);
tx.commit();
...

Comment: try adding @Transcational on method

Comment: On which method? BaseSession class is not a transaction overriding class (EntityTransaction)!
Actually, promote.session.BaseSession.saveBulk() {
 ... 
 tx = emBulk.getTransaction(); 
 if(!tx.isActive()){ 
  tx.begin(); 
 } 
 emBulk.persist(obj); 
 tx.commit(); 
 ...
 }